# How to avoid .net framework installs

Tags: .net, windows-8, windows-7, windows-10

Is there a way to have a single version of an application that supports Win7/8/10 without requiring additional .Net installs, ie using default .net version for each OS version?

I know I might be able to enable .net 3.5 in win8 and win10 as part of an installer custom action, but would like to avoid that.

Comment: Uhh...make a web application...

Comment: It's a windows service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is no, but if you enable the optional component you can make it work if you stick with a 2.x profile.

If you require Windows 8 or later, then you can count on the 4.x profile.

- Windows Server 2003 includes .NET 1.1 SP1
- Windows Vista / Windows Server 2008 includes .NET 2.0 (3.0 RTM can be added as an optional component)
- Windows Vista / Windows Server 2008 SP1 includes .NET 2.0 SP1 (3.0 SP1 is an optional component not installed by default on server)
- Windows Vista / Windows Server 2008 SP2 includes .NET 2.0 SP2 (3.0 SP2 is an optional component not installed by default on server)
- Windows 7 / Windows Server 2008 R2 includes .NET 2.0 SP2 (3.5 SP1 is an optional component not installed by default on server)
- Windows 8 includes .NET 4.5 (3.5 SP1 is an optional component deployed via Windows Update)
- Windows 8.1 includes .NET 4.5.1 (3.5 SP1 is an optional component deployed via Windows Update)
- Windows 10 (RTM) includes .NET 4.6 (3.5 SP1 is an optional component deployed via Windows Update)
- Windows 10 (November 2015 update) includes .NET 4.6.1 (3.5 SP1 is an optional component deployed via Windows Update)

See [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb822049.aspx)

> No version of .NET is included with Windows XP by default.